# ssh - can't use ProxyCommand for intermediate host, but can use rsync

Tags: ssh, rsync, ssh-tunneling

Struggling to figure out where I'm going wrong here

I need to move files from server A to server C via intermediate host server B

I can do this using rsync for a single file easily with the following command

`rsync -avLuR -e "ssh -A user@serverB ssh" myFile.txt user@serverC:/home/user`

However, in order to speed up the rate of transfer I wanted rsync to reuse a master ssh connection, so I've been attempting to do this by modifying `~/.ssh/config`

For example:

```
Host serverC
    User user
    ProxyCommand ssh serverB -W %h:%p

Host serverB
    User user
```

However, trying to ssh to server C from server A using this config results in the following output:

```
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Which as far as I'm aware, is a generic error that could mean many things. One of which is that `AllowTCPForwarding`is disabled, but surely that couldn't be the case if my rsync command does work?

Worth clarifying that I'm using OpenSSH_5.3p1, so using newer capabilities like `ProxyJump` is not an option (AFAIK even `-W` had to be backported to this version)

Comment: the rsync-command and the ~/.ssh/config is both on ServerA? I don't know much about the proxy-command, but I think you are missing the AgentForward like you did with the `-A`. Are you sure, ProxyCommand is not opening a new connection every time? Maybe you also want to have a look at Control{Master,Path}

Comment: yup, both on serverA. I thought about the agent forwarding with `ProxyCommand` but it gave back the same issue. However, I was just able to use `ssh -t user@serverB ssh user@serverC` so I'm looking at setting that up with Control{Master,Path} as an alternative

Comment: Two comments: when you use the chained ssh you are not using TCP forwarding, you’re running the second ssh within the main channel of the first. Second: why can’t you just build a file list to have multiple files transferred in one rsync operation?

Comment: I actually got this working a couple of hours ago using `nc` instead of `-W`, which was confusing as from what I've read `OpenSSH_5.3p1` should have the capability for `-W`

On the TCP Forwarding, learning as I go, I can see now rsync ssh is very different from what I was doing

As for the file list, I had composed a file list to loop through, above was just an example